# Twitter Bootstrap accordion background bullets

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a bullet change/swap when the accordion of a Twitter Bootstrap collapses and expands. I used a background image for the bullets.

Right now, in this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/fBd4a/10/, when the page loads, the bullet applied is '-'. But after the item is expanded, and collapsed, it retains the '+' bullet. I would like the '+' bullet from the beginning.

Thanks.

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.accordion .accordion-group .accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.collapsed {background: #e9e8e8 url(http://i.imgur.com/pdB4oDz.png) no-repeat 0 11px;} 
.accordion .accordion-group .accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle {background: #e9e8e8 url(http://i.imgur.com/9zfyr43.png) no-repeat 0 20px;}

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the code to start with the plus sign then add the `collapsed` class to the `a` that have the class of `accordion-toggle`.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBd4a/12/)

Comment: Wow, what a quick and efficient answer. Thanks, Blake.